# Filter an imageCollection by a given month for a range of years in Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, trmm

I want to filter TRMM precipitation data for a defined region and specific month, for example January, over 10 years.

To be clear, I only want observations referring to January for each year in a given range.

I've tried using `.filterDate()`, but this does not seem like the right method for this task.

What `ee.ImageCollection` method is best suited for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `calendarRange()` filter:

```
images.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1, 1, 'month'))
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/cc7bb40f71679117f69ac530373e0fa9